# require path in browserify is not recognized

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have below project structure as shown in the screenshot below. Both index.js and test.js are located at the same path i.e. ./assets/js/ but still the path is not recognized. The error says

> Error: Cannot find module 'test.js' from
>   'C:\Users\meghshyam\desktop\browserifyproj\assets\js'

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var test = require('./test.js');`

This way you are letting node know that its a file in the same folder